# Use different HTML code for desktop and mobile version

Tags: php, html, css, mobile, alignment

On my [website](http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/) I am trying to change how the divs look depending on the screen size. I already have a css file that deals with that. When I use the mobile version the titles in this div are like that : 
[image]
So, you can see that the title does not fit in one line.

The code is :

```
<div class="row"> 
              <div class="6u"> <section> <h3 class="image-radius img"><img src="images/datorama.jpg"/>DATA VISUALISATION ENGINEER</h3> 
                  <p><b>Datorama</b></p> 
                  <p>•  Digital data analysis and automation</p> 
                  <p>•  User-Interface interaction improvement</p> 
                  <p>•  Visualisation of the insights </p></section> 
              </div>
```

So, I changed one line of the code by adding the `<br>` :

```
<div class="6u"> <section> <h3 class="image-radius img"><img src="images/datorama.jpg"/> <br>DATA VISUALISATION ENGINEER</h3>
```

So, the mobile version is fine. But when I use this, my desktop version is like that:
[image]

but it used to be like that :

[image]

My question is, how can I have a different version of html code depending on the screen size? I have the css code but it is going to be hard to set it up. Now I just have to add a `<br>`. Is there a way to add like an (IF desktop version, checking the css file --> html code version 1, else --> html code version 2).

Comment: Yes, you *can* do browser sniffing. However, it is a very bad method to use. It is far superior to use CSS to properly arrange (and hide) divs on the page. What you do, if you want to go the poor route, is look for "Android" or "Mobile" in the user agent $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Comment: You can use css media queries but please don't do this. Just offer a mobile version and desktop version like Stackoverflow. Don't dynamically change the display based on the screen size. This is annoying when users want to see the full site and you don't respect when they request the desktop site.

Comment: @kainaw Can you explain why you think using the user agent is a bad method? It's how Chrome from android can have the feature of "Request Desktop site".

Comment: @DaveChen Browser sniffing is not new. It is very old. It has never worked great. It only works "good enough." It doesn't take into account that the user agent is free text that can be altered at any time. There is no authority to ensure that what you sniff for will be valid. If you don't keep up with the sniffing logic constantly, it will go stale and stop working because new agents are being used.

Comment: @Dave Chen I have to create a mobile version too. If I can find a simple template then it is ok. But I no longer have time for this. It is just for a hobby.

Comment: @kainaw So? If the user wants to view your website in desktop mode why are you undermining them by detecting their screen size and forcing them to use your mobile version? Using the user-agent or user language headers is respectful to the user, and by also proving them the option to change these options at anytime provides a good user experience.

Comment: @DaveChen You are assuming that browser sniffing is the ONLY way to get the desktop mode. That is a terrible assumption - almost as bad as assuming that browser sniffing will work for all web browsers. Why not have a cookie that the user can set with a simple link or button that says "Show Desktop Site" and then omit CSS to display the mobile site? Simple. Easy. Only fails if the client doesn't support cookies. Doesn't depend on every-changing user agent strings.

Comment: @kainaw When have I stated that using the user agent is the only way? I've already mentioned giving them the option to change between modes. **I am arguing against this point**: `It is far superior to use CSS to properly arrange (and hide) divs on the page.`. I'm stating that it's better to use the user agent and or cookies instead of using screen size. It is **not** better to use css/media queries than using a link `Show Desktop site`.

Comment: @DaveChen My most recent reply was in response to "If the user wants to view your website in desktop mode why are you undermining them". I read that as a claim that if you don't use browser sniffing, you are automatically undermining the user. But, you obviously want to return to the original statement, which I will summarize as  "Browser sniffing is not great." I have spent many years fiddling with my browser agent string because stupid sites use browser sniffing and make improper conclusions from it. I hate it. I won't use it. I don't suggest that others use it. There are other ways.

Comment: @kainaw Chrome for mobile has a feature called "Request Desktop Site". This changes your user-agent to a desktop one. So if you're using css media queries, you are still going to show the mobile version on a mobile device, even after the user changes their preferences. This is undermining the user's choice to request the desktop site.

Comment: @DaveChen You are correct that "Request Desktop Site" changes the user agent. It also changes the media width to 4 times the actual device size. So, if I check the media width, I get 4 times the actual device's media width. Therefore, I will see it as a wide-screen, not a narrow phone. Once again - you can sniff the browser or you can use CSS media rules and get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find soemthing here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```
// your mobile css version
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
    // your desktop css version
}
```

Comment: You will also want the meta tag <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> to keep phones from altering the scale and claiming to have four times the pixels they actually have.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

```
function isMobile() {
  $deviceList = array(
    '/iphone/i' => 'iPhone', 
    '/ipod/i' => 'iPod', 
    '/ipad/i' => 'iPad', 
    '/android/i' => 'Android'
  );

  foreach($deviceList as $deviceKey => $deviceOS) {
    if(preg_match($deviceKey, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        // echo your content for mobile devices
    }
  }
}
```

These are not all mobile devices that can be provided by `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, you could check [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) for a full list